# Possible bug of Exporting as HTMLFragment at Linux

Tags: export, linux, html, conversion

This is the result of *Mathematica* 10.0.2 of Linux Version. There are two style inside one tag, and this fragment cannot be Imported as XML by *Mathematica*.[image]
[image]

This is the result of *Mathematica* 10.1 of Windows Version. This is the right result.[image]

Is this a bug? and is this fixed in *Mathematica* 10.1 of Linux Version?

```
item = 
Item[Style[Hyperlink["test", "test"], FontColor -> Red, 
FontSize -> 20, Bold], ItemSize -> {30, 5}];
ImportString[ExportString[item, "HTMLFragment"],"XML"]
```

Comment: I get your correct result on 10.1 and Fedora.

Comment: I get your correct result on 10.1 and the bad result on 10.0.2 on OSX. Could you please make it make explicit that the `ImportString` call is part of the test?

Comment: Could you please clean up this question and only use screenshots for output? I feel that the bugs tags has been applied over early and the fact that the question is not completely clear is not helping.