# Dealing Repeated pattern in StringReplace

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

#### A problem about StringReplace

---

When I'm running into this problem [possible [bug]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/possible-bug-of-exporting-as-htmlfragment-at-linux)

```
str11 = "<strong style=\"font-size:20px\" style=\"color:#dfa57c\" 

style=\"font-size:20px\" style=\"color:#dfa57c\" class=\"new\">";

StringCases[str11, 

 Repeated[Shortest["style=\"" ~~ ___], {2, 10}] ~~ "\""]

(*
    {style="font-size:20px" style="color:#dfa57c",style="font-size:20px" style="color:#dfa57c"
}
*)
```

There is a problem of the above code, there are two result, how can I get just one `Max` repeated result? Something like the effect of Longest

Here is like the following result.

```
StringCases[str11, Repeated[Shortest["style=\"" ~~ ___], {4}] ~~ "\""]

(*
    {style="font-size:20px" style="color:#dfa57c" style="font-size:20px" style="color:#dfa57c"
}
*)

StringReplace[str11, 

 x : Repeated[Shortest["style=\"" ~~ ___], {2, 20}] ~~ "\""]

(*
    <strong ="font-size:20px" style="color:#dfa57c ="font-size:20px" style="color:#dfa57c clas
s="new">
*)

StringReplace[str11, 

 p : Repeated[Shortest["style=\"" ~~ ___], {4}] ~~ "\"" :> 

  "style=" <> 

   StringReplace[

    StringJoin[

Riffle[StringSplit[

  StringReplace[p, "style=" -> ""], {"style=", " "}], 

 ";", {2, -1, 2}]], "\";\"" -> "; "] <> "\""]

(*
    <strong style="font-size:20px; color:#dfa57c; font-size:20px; color:#dfa57c;" class="new">
*)
```

Question: Can the `count` be removed? Are there any simpler solutions?

```
htmlStringTrim[x_] := (count = StringCount[x, "style"]; 

  StringReplace[x, 

   p : (Repeated[Shortest["style=\"" ~~ ___], {count}]) ~~ "\"" :> 

    StringJoin[

 Riffle[StringSplit[p, {"\" style=\""}], "; ", {2, -1, 2}]] <> 

"\""])

htmlStringTrim[str11]

(*
    <strong style="font-size:20px; color:#dfa57c; font-size:20px; color:#dfa57c; " class="new"
>
*)
```

---

Thanks for Mr.Wizard's answer.

```
htmlStringTrimNew[x_] := 
  StringReplace[x, 
   p : (("style=\"" ~~ Except["\""] .. ~~ "\"" ~~ 
     Whitespace | "") ..) :> (
 "style=\"" <> 
  StringJoin[
   StringInsert[StringReplace[#, "\"" :> ""], ";", -2] & /@ 
    StringSplit[p, {"style=\""}], "\""])];
```

Comment: I think this should answer your question, unless I missed the point which is possible here. - [using the StringCase function and Shortest option](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72283/5478)

Comment: HyperGroups do you agree with Kuba that your question is answered in the linked Q&A?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't agree that, the most confused problem of the question is how to match the repeated pattern. that problem is matching pattern from left to right something like `Map[StringCases[#, 
   Shortest["|uniprotkb:" ~~ aa__ ~~ "(gene name)"] -> aa, 
   Overlaps -> True] &, test1]`

Comment: @HyperGroups could you reduce the question to the unique problem. It is so large now it discourages from reading, imo.

Comment: @Kuba how about now

Comment: Okay.  I don't know a better solution to the Repeated problem but I'll think about it.  Incidentally `htmlStringTrim` does not give me the output that you show; instead I get: `"<strong style=\"font-size:20px; color:#dfa57c\" 
style=\"font-size:20px; color:#dfa57c; \" class=\"new\">"`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hi, I found that's the problem about there generate a new line `\\` in StackExchange in `str11`, which will affect the function.  Now I‘ve removed that.

Comment: I posted an answer relating to the pattern (which also handles the newline).  Please check it.  Are you interested in alternative implementation of `htmlStringTrim`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, welcome, I add one not so concise just now

Comment: Is performance or clarity more important for this code?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard performance is not so important in dealing with that bug I think, since there will limited number of `style` will be in a string, considering `Inline style of css.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this matches what you want it to:

```
str11 = "<strong style=\"font-size:20px\" style=\"color:#dfa57c\" 
  style=\"font-size:20px\" style=\"color:#dfa57c\" class=\"new\">";

StringCases[str11, ("style=\"" ~~ Except["\""] .. ~~ "\"" ~~ Whitespace | "") ..]
```

> ```
> {"style=\"font-size:20px\" style=\"color:#dfa57c\" 
>  style=\"font-size:20px\" style=\"color:#dfa57c\" "}
> ```

Comment: nice, the use of Except is important where I should make progress.